# Integrating application security with GeoServer security?

Tags: geoserver, wms, wfs, java

I'm going to develop a map server with my own logic and entities. It will have a Postgres database, user management, specific layers with certain types, WFS, WMS, etc.
I'm going to use **springframework** and **GeoServer** as the GeoServer is an open source project.
I have user a management problem. How can I integrate my own project security with that of GeoServer? I mean how can I add a user or role or group or assgin a role to a user programmatically? How can I authenticate with geoserver programmatically?
As you know you can manage layers, workspaces, etc by **GeoServer-manager**. But it does not have user management REST API!

I've developed a map server that maintains layers info and I want it to support WFS and WMS. I want to grant access to my users of layers.
It was the most details of my application.

Comment: As it stands I think your question is too broad when, as per the [Tour], we look for one question per question.  However, even focussed into its own question, I suspect that each of the three questions may still be too broad so I recommend trying to focus them further.

Comment: I think you're planning to do it wrong. You should just add a plugin to geoserver that handles your specific situation. Otherwise your map server will have to duplicate all of the GeoServer parts. Its hard to say what your plugin should do without much more detail on the specific logic and data types you are trying to support. Perhaps you can edit your question?

Comment: Thank you @BradHards. How can I add a plugin to geoserver? Do you have any documents and helpful links?

Comment: When you fix your question (to add the missing detail), I may (or may not) be able to help.

Comment: @BradHards now you can answer the best

Comment: When I said "much more detail on the specific logic and data types you are trying to support", I meant it. You still haven't told us what you want to do. I see you asked the same question on the geoserver devel list. That isn't going to help. You *must* provide as much detail in the question as you expect in the answer.

Comment: I have almost the same problem. please see [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150904/can-i-use-web-map-service-module-and-web-feature-service-module-of-geoserver).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used [geo-fence](https://github.com/geoserver/geofence), a geoserver plugin for security management. It has a Restful API for adding,managing,ect of users,roles,rules,....