# Can I use "Web Map Service Module" and "Web Feature Service Module" of Geoserver in my project?

Tags: geoserver, wms, wfs, java, geotools

I'm developing a GIS application with **java Spring Framework** and **GeoTools library**. I have some **vector** layer. I want to get this **layers** with **wms** and **wfs** protocols.
I've downloaded geoserver code. It includes module as bellow:

- Main Module
- Core Platform Module
- Web Map Service Module
- Web Feature Service Module
- and etc.

Can I use **Web Map Service Module** and **Web Feature Service Module** of **Geoserver** in my project?
If yes, **How**?
I want a sample code to use these modules **apart from geoserver**. Help me please.

Comment: Yes you can. How I don't know. I've never done it. A suggestion to ease the burden of porting code would be to deploy and configure a GeoServer Web Server as part of your deployment. But since you don't talk much about the deployment/structure of your GIS application I'm unsure if this suggestion is appropriate. If it just a desktop app then it is perhaps not appropriate.

Comment: Are you using Maven as your build tool? GeoServer uses it to help manage dependencies. It would help in using these GeoServer modules in your project and manage the 3rd party dependencies.

Comment: yea I'm using Maven. [it's here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qCiJ6.png)

Comment: I would direct you enquires to the Developers Mailing List. Sign up for access to this list here http://geoserver.org/comm/

Answer (score 2):

You can check the code out of the repository and do pretty much anything you like with it. You might also want to look at the [GeoTools](http://geotools.org/)  code that underlies much of the GeoServer code.

GeoServer code is licensed under the [GPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License) - so there are some restrictions on what you can do with it, mostly related to releasing programs without [releasing your changes to the buyer/public](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License#Linking_and_derived_works).

The GeoTools code is licensed under the [LGPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License) which is slightly more relaxed.

Answer (score 1):

I would deploy `GeoServer` as a companion Web App. It has many configuration options, security features and a good user interfaces to control it.

If you don't want to expose a whole GeoServer Web App you could put a proxy in front of it and only expose the URLs that allows appropriate access to the layers via WMS and WFS.

Let GeoServer control access to your data, and then you can worry about developing you GIS application. Don't re-invent the wheel, and don't make it harder for yourself.

Comment: I'm not allowed using **geoserver**. I'm only allowed to using **web map service** and **web feature service** modules. For this reason, I only want to add these modules to my project and then use it.