# How do I develop some of WFS and WMS methods?

Tags: geoserver, wms, wfs

I want to develop a **GIS** application. My application has some options as following:

- **Users** with different access to **layers**
- **Layers** with different source like `postgis` and  `shp`
- `OpenLayers-3.6.0` in client side
- OpenLayers `layers` get its data via `WFS` and `WMS` protocols.

I want to use `Spring` java framework as application structure and `Hibernate` for **Non Spatial Data** transactions and `geotools` library for **Spatial Data**.

The best **solution** for me is using **GEOSERVER**, but I'm not allowed to use it.

I don't need all method of `WFS` and `WMS`, I need methods as following:

- `getFeatuers`, `transaction` and `getCapabilities` methods in `WFS` Protocol.
- `getMap`, `WMSGetFeatureInfo` and '`getCapabilities` methods in `WMS` protocol.

I have some questions:

- Can I separate `WFS` and `WMS` module of geoserver and add these to my project and use these? If yes, Any reference?
- How can I develop the methods of `WFS` and `WMS` Protocols(I don't want to have a `WFS` and `WMS` server, I only want to implement some of its methods)?

Comment: I have asked a similar question [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150904/can-i-use-web-map-service-module-and-web-feature-service-module-of-geoserver)